# Picture Capture fails using Camera in flutter

Tags: flutter, image, dart, camera, face-detection

I am working on an application which captures image using camera live streaming and send it to next page. I have used takePicture method to capture. Below is the code that i have used in my application.

````
    class CameraApp extends StatefulWidget {
      const CameraApp({super.key});
    
      @override
      State<CameraApp> createState() => _CameraAppState();
    }
    
    class _CameraAppState extends State<CameraApp> {
      late CameraController _controller;
      @override
      void initState() {
        // TODO: implement initState
        super.initState();
        _controller = CameraController(
          cameras[0],
         ResolutionPreset.max);
         _controller.initialize().then((_) {
          if(!mounted){
            return;
          }
          setState(() {});
            
          }).catchError((Object e){
            if(e is CameraException){
              switch(e.code){
                case 'CaneraAccessDenied':
                print("access was denided");
                break;
                default:
                 print(e.description);
                 break;
              }
            }
          });
         
      }```
    ```
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return  Scaffold(
       body:Center(
         child: Stack(
          children: [
            Container(
          height: double.infinity,
          child:CameraPreview(_controller),
            ),
     
         Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
          Center(
            child: Container(
              margin:EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              child: MaterialButton(
                  onPressed:() async{
                    if(!_controller.value.isInitialized){
                      return null;
                    }
                     if(!_controller.value.isTakingPicture){
                      return null;
                     }
    
                     try{
                      await _controller.setFlashMode(FlashMode.auto);
                      XFile picture = await _controller.takePicture();
                       Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context)=>ImagePreview(file:picture)));
                     } on CameraException catch(e){
                      debugPrint("Error occured : $e");
                      return null;
                     }
                  },
                   color:Colors.white,
                    child:const Text('Click'),
                  
                  
                  ),
            ),
          ),
         ],)
            
          ],
         ),
       )
        );
      }
    }
````

The above code is a complete screen of live camera opening and a button to capture image .
Its not capturing image when I click on the button.

camera version:-  camera: ^0.9.4+11

below is flutter doctor:

[image: flutter doctor]

Comment: Please add you camera full code

Comment: @PriyanshuPaliwal i have added full code. please check.